# post_save signal isn't called

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I've already read all related questions.

I have two Django projects, and signals work fine in one, but do not work in second one (I've just copy-pasted code and changed names respectively).

I have an orders app with Order model. App is included in INSTALLED_APPS setting.

I have app config in apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class OrdersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'orders'

    def ready(self):
        super(OrdersConfig, self).ready()

        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        import signals
```

`__init__.py`:

```
default_app_config = 'orders.apps.OrdersConfig'
```

And, finally, signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def order_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print 'Post save'
    if created:
        print 'Created'
        send_email_new_order.delay(settings.MODERATOR_EMAIL, instance.pk)
```

And signal does not getting called. Why?

Django 1.10.3.

Comment: Try defining your signals at the end of your models.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### When would post_save be fired?

What the document says:  At the end of the save method.

What it really means:  At the end of the successful completion of the save method.

### When would the signal not be fired?

1. If the `save` method does not successfully save the object (such as when an `IntegrityError` occurs)
2. When you call `MyModel.objects.update()`
3. When you override the `save` method and forget to call the superclass method.
4. When your signal receiver hasn't been successfully registered.

### How to register the receiver

Simplest is to use the `@receiver` decorator as you have done. The alternative is to use

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

pre_save.connect(order_save, sender='app_label.MyModel')
```

### Where should this code be placed?

Nowadays, the [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) states that

> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
>   anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
>   application’s root module and its models module to minimize
>   side-effects of importing code.

That is probably why in this instance you have created a file called signals.py and place your code inside that and gone to all that trouble with the AppConfig class and the ready method. But funnily enough, the [Django 1.6 manual](http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.x/topics/signals.html?highlight=signals) says:

> You can put signal handling and registration code anywhere you like.
>   However, you’ll need to make sure that the module it’s in gets
>   imported early on so that the signal handling gets registered before
>   any signals need to be sent. This makes your app’s models.py a good
>   place to put registration of signal handlers.

So if you are having trouble getting your signal receiver registered you can actually try putting your code in `models.py` or `views.py` and leave out the bits from AppConfig (maybe even remove AppConfig completely)

If you want to carry out the registration in AppConfig, and you are having trouble with `@reciever` and/or imports, you can try

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from app_label.signals import my_reciever

def ready(self):
    pre_save.connect(my_reciever, sender='app_label.MyModel')
```

### How to avoid repeats?

Does the signal get fired twice? Make sure that you register the receiver only once. If you register it in `AppConfig`, leave it out of `models.py` and vice verce

Comment: If you put your signal in your model file, is the sender=self?

Answer (score 6):

Are you aaaaaabsolutely sure the correct `signals` is imported? (`print('hi, signals here')` in the module?)

You might want to use an absolutely qualified import (`import orders.signals`) or a relative one (`import .signals as signals`), too.

Comment: Hm, checked with print, it's called twice — is it ok?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have another app also named `signals`?

Try relative import in the `ready` method: `from . import signals`