# Creating users with custom attributes: the post_save signal seems not to be received

Tags: python, django

I want to create users based on info from a CSV file. My users have two additional attributes, 'pensum' and 'stopien':

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stopien = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pensum = models.IntegerField()
```

This is my import routine:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

#so that a created user would already have 'stopien' and 'pensum' attributes to be set
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_employee(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Employee.objects.create(user=instance)

#row 0 and 1: username; 2: email, 3: stopien, 4: pensum
def importusers(filename):
    dataReader = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=str(u';').encode('utf-8'), quotechar=str(u'"').encode('utf-8'))
    for row in dataReader:
        if row[0] != 'name': # Ignore the header row, import everything else
            #the following is the intended username, which at this moment will be used as a password too (will fix this later)
            uzytkownik=row[0]+row[1]
            newuser = User.objects.create_user(uzytkownik, row[2], uzytkownik, first_name=row[0], last_name=row[1])
            newuser.save()
            newuser.pensum = row[4]
            newuser.stopien = row[3]
            newuser.save()
```

However, the receiver seems never to be invoked: users get created, but without any 'stopien' or 'pensum'. No error is given. What am I doing wrong?

(I'm also importing django.db.models.signals at the end of models.py.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post\_save signal isn't called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746137/post-save-signal-isnt-called)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I read the answer to the above question and 1) my object, that is, the User, is successfully saved, so the signal should be fired; and 2) I am doing all this from the shell, importing my files manually. (The code above is from my models.py and utils.py, and I make sure they are imported before I run the importusers routine.)

Comment: as mentioned in that Q&A successfully saving an instance is only part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a related model, not a custom user model. `pensum` and `stopien` are fields of your related model, so you should set them on the related model instance - setting them on the `user` instance is technically legal but the values won't be persisted since they are plain instance attributes, not associated with any field of the model class.

You can either switch to a [proper custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), or you'll have to create the related model manually (and update your signal handler to use `get_or_create()` instead to avoid trying to create the related `Employee` instance twice)

Comment: Thank you. I decided to remove the signal handler altogether and, after the new user is saved for the first time, use 'Employee.objects.create(user=nowyuzytkownik) [NEWLINE] nowyuzytkownik.employee.pensum = row[4] [NEWLINE] nowyuzytkownik.employee.stopien = row[3] [NEWLINE] nowyzutkownik.employee.save()'.

Comment: You could pass `pensum` and `stopien` as keyword args to `Employee.create()` - this would save you a db query.