# How to make allauth accept only gmail addresses belonging to a certain institute?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-allauth

Example:-

qwe123@***pilani.bits-pilani.ac.in***

I think i just need to check if the "template ending" is present in the email address or not but the problem is where to check it in the allauth package

Comment: Is this sorted out?

Comment: No the ways specified did not work

Comment: please use the term "Does not work" here on stackoverflow if and only if you want to attract downvotes. For all other situtions explain what happened such as an error message that came up

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a direct way to do this in django-allauth. The best bet is to listen for the [user_signed_up](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) signal and disable an account that does not have the required email address format.

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def after_user_signed_up(request, user):
    if user.email.endswith('pilani.bits-pilani.ac.in'):
         # do something for valid accounts
    else :
         user.is_active = False
         user.save()
         # raise SomeException
```

If you have more than one address pattern, you will need multiple if statements or possibly create a model for the allowed email address patterns.

Comment: well i am just confused abt where exactly to include this code.

Comment: usual place for signals handlers is in views.py, but it can also go in models.py too. For more info if needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746137/post-save-signal-isnt-called/40883331#40883331

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it. But certainly there are few indirect ways. You can check using [email header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331351/python-email-header-decoding-utf-8). From here you can get basic info about the email. You can store `ip address` and filter using that for a particular domain.